# WebPartConnection via XML based Provisioning

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, provisioning

I can provision the following on a page via XML-based provisioning:

- Query Filter webpart
- List View webpart

I am trying to connect the ListView webpart to the Query Filter webpart so I can filter by a querystring called EventID.

Although, I do not get any deployment errors, the web parts provisioned on the test page are not connected. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Note: This has to work through XML provisioning only.

Here is the provisioning XML:

```
      <Module Name="SitePages_1033\STS\doctemp\smartpgs" Url="SitePages" SetupPath="1033\STS\doctemp\smartpgs" RootWebOnly="FALSE" Path="Files\SitePages">
    <File Url="TestPage.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published" Path="spstd1.aspx" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="True" ReplaceContent="True">
<!-- Query filter webpart -->
      <AllUsersWebPart WebPartOrder="1" WebPartZoneID="FullPage" ID="g_d33fc3e2_b620_4508_89db_3cf50a4d65f3">
        <![CDATA[<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.QueryStringFilterWebPart, Microsoft.Office.Server.FilterControls, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this web part.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="FilterName" type="string">EventID</property>
        <property name="SendEmptyWhenNoValues" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
        <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
        <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="DefaultValue" type="string">1</property>
        <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
        <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Cannot import this web part.</property>
        <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Filters the contents of Web Parts using values passed via the query string.</property>
        <property name="QueryStringParameterName" type="string">EventID</property>
        <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string">/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif</property>
        <property name="MultipleValueHandling" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.FilterMultipleValueHandling, Microsoft.Office.Server.FilterControls, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">SendFirst</property>
        <property name="ValueSeparator" type="string" />
        <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Height" type="string" />
        <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
        <property name="Title" type="string">EventID Filter</property>
        <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string">/_layouts/images/wp_Filter.gif</property>
        <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
        <property name="Width" type="string" />
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
      <!-- Calendar ListView-->
      <View List="Lists/Calendar" DisplayName="" Url="" DefaultView="FALSE" BaseViewID="3" Type="HTML" WebPartOrder="2" WebPartZoneID="FullPage" ContentTypeID="0x" ID="g_ee1ae5df_2af1_4cd6_b021_0774e4ea8fe4" Hidden="TRUE" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE">
        <BinarySerializedWebPart>
          <GUIDMap>
            <GUID Id="685cffd2_7df8_4d10_8844_2d2bdfa01314" ListUrl="Lists/MeetingAgendaItems" />
          </GUIDMap>
          <WebPart ID="{ee1ae5df-2af1-4cd6-b021-0774e4ea8fe4}" WebPartIdProperty="g_ee1ae5df_2af1_4cd6_b021_0774e4ea8fe4"
                   WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" List="{$ListId:Lists/Calendar;}" Type="1" Flags="8396813" DisplayName="" Version="36"
                   Url="~site/SitePages/AgendaBuilder.aspx" WebPartOrder="2" WebPartZoneID="FullPage" IsIncluded="True" FrameState="0" WPTypeId="{a6524906-3fd2-ee4e-23ee-252d3c6e0dc9}">
          </WebPart>
        </BinarySerializedWebPart>
      </View>
<WebPartConnection ConsumerConnectionPointID="DFWP Filter Consumer ID" ConsumerID="g_ee1ae5df_2af1_4cd6_b021_0774e4ea8fe4"
                       ProviderConnectionPointID="ITransformableFilterValues" ProviderID="g_d33fc3e2_b620_4508_89db_3cf50a4d65f3" ID="c1077384606">
        <WebPartTransformer Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages">
          <![CDATA[<WebPartPages:TransformableFilterValuesToParametersTransformer ConsumerFieldNames="CalendarItemReference" ProviderFieldNames="EventID" />]]>
        </WebPartTransformer>
      </WebPartConnection>
 </File>
  </Module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have not put the code of `ListViewWebPart` inside `<![CDATA[]]>` tag. Something like this:

```
<View List="Lists/ClientCalendar" BaseViewID="2" Type="CALENDAR" WebPartZoneID="Content Zone" WebPartOrder="1" ID="ClientCalandar">
                       <![CDATA[
              <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
                <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
                <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart</TypeName>
               <Title>Client Calendar</Title>
               <TitleUrl>clientcalendar.aspx</TitleUrl>
             </WebPart>
           ]]>

          </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
            List="Lists/Tasks"
            BaseViewID="5"
            WebPartZoneID="Header"
            WebPartOrder="1">
            <![CDATA[

              <webParts>
               <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                <metaData>
                 <type name="**Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart**,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                 <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
                </metaData>
                <data>
                 <properties>
                  <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="Title" type="string">My Task</property>
                  <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
                  <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">False</property>
                  <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">TitleOnly</property>
                 </properties>
                </data>
               </webPart>
              </webParts>
             ]]>
          </View>
```

You must put **"XsltListViewWebPart"** instead of  **"QueryStringFilterWebPart"**